# How to create a dictionary and a dataframe in Python through loops

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe

For example, if

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
```

I'd like to create a dictionary like

```
dict1={'1':[1,1,1],'2':[2,2,2],'3':[3,3,3]}
```

How can I realize it through loops?  I tried

```
dict1=dict().fromkeys(list1)
for i in range(len(list1)):
    dict1['i']=list2[i]
```

But I failed, so is there anyone can help me deal with this problem? 
One more question, if I firstly create an empty dataframe, df1

```
df1=pd.DataFrame()
```

and I hope use the elements in list1 as columns' name of df1. How can I realize it?

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: `dict(zip(map(str, list1),list2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip()` with `dict()` to convert the two lists to a dictionary:

```
dict(zip(list1, list2))
# {1: [1, 1, 1], 2: [2, 2, 2], 3: [3, 3, 3]}
```

To construct a data frame with `list1` as columns:

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(list1, list2)))

#   1   2   3
#0  1   2   3
#1  1   2   3
#2  1   2   3
```

Answer (score 0):

You failed if you tried to use

```
dict1['i']
```

instead of

```
dict1[i]
```

Since you are only using the letter/string `i` as the key whilst you have keys generated from the list i.e.  `['1','2','3']`

If you are starting off you should look at coding it up like this then move to move pythonic ways.

```
dict1 = {}
for i, key in enumerate(map(str,list1)):
     if key not in dict1:
          dict1[key] = list2[i]
```

This will get you thinking about dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can just append the items into the dictionary if you want to use loops.

```
d = {}
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(len(l)): 
    d[i] = l[i]
```

When you print d you will have 
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}